# Powershell HomeDirectory not created on fileserver filesystem

Tags: powershell, active-directory, fileserver, home-directory

I am having a weird problem using Powershell and setting a HomeDirectory via the cmdlet

```
Set-ADUser -Identity "user" -HomeDirectory "\\fileserver\home$\user"
```

Even though the cmdlet is working and setting the values in the AD, the necessary folder on the fileserver "\fileserver\home$\user" will not be created.

I have also unsuccessfully tried the same with the initial creation

```
New-ADUser -Name "user" -HomeDirectory "\\fileserver\home$\user"
```

I have started the Powershell on the Exchange server as domain-admin via UAC and imported the module ActiveDirectory via

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

Instead of using the UNC-path with NetBIOS-hostnames I also tried the FQDN \fileserver.domain.local\ and also the ip adrress \ip\

If I am using the cd command to enter the UNC-path via Powershell, it does also work, I can also create directories.

```
cd \\fileserver\home$
mkdir test_dir
```

Still, the directory will not be created. 
If I am using the AD GUI, and try to alter the HomeDirectory-path, the folder will be created.

Any hints?
Many thanks
PS: 2008R2 x64, Exchange 2010, 1x Exchange, 1x AD controller, 1x fileserver

Comment: Does it throw any errors? Are you running this from an elevated PowerShell session?

Comment: I was running into the same problem at one of my clients and ended up creating the folders in powershell.

Comment: No, it does not throw any Errors. I will follow up procedure in creating the homedirectory including ACLs afterwards, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is worth mentioning the following from [Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/06/04/creating-a-home-drive-with-windows-powershell-part-1.aspx)

> Remember, all we have done is edit a field in Active Directory. The
>   file system on the foreign server has no clue about the information
>   presented within Active Directory. When you edit those fields in the
>   GUI, the user folder and permissions are provisioned as a function of
>   the code within that GUI interface—they are not a function of Active
>   Directory.

Much like Paul suggested I think you just need to create the folder yourself. Linked in that article is information about setting permissions for the file share as well. I imagine you already have that done.

```
NEW-ITEM –path "\\fileserver\home$\user" -type directory -force
```

Comment: Another option would be to autmoatically create a missing home folder via a logon script (provided that permissions on the userhome share allow users to create folders).

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I am going to create the Folder and set its correct ACLs for the user.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to do this will be to create home folder for all users if doesn't exist.  Create a schedule task with event id 4720 to do this automatically

Connect home folder path and drive letter.

```
Get-ADUser -filter * | % { Set-ADUser $_ -HomeDrive "H:" -HomeDirectory ('\\server\home$\' + $_.SamAccountName) }
```

create home folders for each users:-

```
ForEach( $User in (Get-ADUser -filter * | if( -not ( -HomeDrive "H:" -HomeDirectory ('\\server\home$\' + $_.SamAccountName) )
```